# Any way to track who set configurations in Google Adwords?

Tags: google-ads-api

Is there a way to know who set a configuration or setting a certain way in Adwords? More specifically, someone who had access to our account set a bunch of conversion actions and I would like to know who.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for change history, which is only available through the interface last time I checked.

https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/19888?hl=en

> You can find change history in the "Tools" menu, or go directly to the tool by visiting [adwords.google.com/ch/ChangeHistory](http://adwords.google.com/ch/ChangeHistory)